# Unity/C# Find object which have generic component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I was totally exhausted at drag and drop components in inspector.

What I want to do was find every object which have component that i had chosen with T

```
void GetAllGameObjectWhichHave<T>(ref int cnt, GameObject[] f_array, GameObject transformForSearch)
{

    foreach (Transform trans in transformForSearch.transform)
    {
        GetAllGameObjectWhichHave<T>(ref cnt, f_array, trans.gameObject);

        T temp = trans.gameObject.GetComponent<T>();

        if (temp != null && cnt < f_array.Length)
        {
            f_array[cnt++] = trans.gameObject;
        }
    }
}
```

and i used like this

```
//OnAwake()
GetAllGameObjectWhichHave<Rigidbody2D>(ref zeroInt, enoughArray, TopHierarchyObj);
```

This recursive function gets EVERY gameobject and save them at f_array. It cannot filter and 'temp' was always not null.

**T temp = trans.gameObject.GetComponent()** doesn't seem working what i meant.

Did i misunderstand something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`FindObjectsOfType<T>()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html). (Yep, the generic variant exists) That will get you an array of all components of a certain type. From there you can do whatever you like.

Or, in case you would like to restrict it to the components found within the children of a certain GameObject, you can use [`GetComponentsInChildren<T>()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html). That will get you an array of all components of a certain type within the children of an object.

Comment: But that finds every object in the scene.....I want to restrict searches only in certain object's hierarchy.

Comment: Adjusted @TaeHanKwon.